# When joining a table to itself to identfy duplicate date in a column, how do you keep it from returning the inverse in the results?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to write a sql statement to return me the list of duplicate items I find in a table. For the sake of simplicity imagine a table named TEST with a rowid column and a text column called column 1 with the following date:

```
rowid | column1
---------------
  1   |   A
  2   |   B
  3   |   C
  4   |   A
  5   |   B
  6   |   C
  7   |   D
```

The query I currently have is:

```
select t1.rowid, t1.column1, t2.rowid, t2.column1
from test t1
inner join test t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.rowid <> t2.rowid
```

It gives me the following results, as I would expect it to do:

```
rowid | column1 | rowid | column1
---------------------------------
  1   |   A     |   4   |   A
  2   |   B     |   5   |   B
  3   |   C     |   6   |   C
  4   |   A     |   1   |   A
  5   |   B     |   2   |   B
  6   |   C     |   3   |   C
```

What I really want is just:

```
rowid | column1 | rowid | column1
---------------------------------
  1   |   A     |   4   |   A
  2   |   B     |   5   |   B
  3   |   C     |   6   |   C
```

What black sql magic to I need to call upon in order to get my desired result?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
select t1.rowid, t1.column1, t2.rowid, t2.column1
from test t1
inner join test t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1 and t1.rowid < t2.rowid
```

Comment: That seems to easy, can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to produce results in the same form as the original table:

```
SELECT t.rowid, t.column1
    FROM (SELECT column1
              FROM test 
              GROUP BY column1
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) q
        INNER JOIN test t
            ON q.column1 = t.column1
    ORDER BY t.column1, t.rowid
```

Comment: that could be useful, in my case it is not what I really need. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
select min(rowid), column1, max(rowid), column1 
from test
group by column1
having count(*)>1
```

Saves doing self-joins or subqueries, gotta be faster.